# Google Analytics filter for WordPress Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

My site is showing hits in Google Analytics when I am updating the site in WordPress. I want to create a filter in the analytics dashboard to exclude these pageviews.

Requirements:

1. works with any url including browsing the site pages. (i.e. not just preview=true pages which has been suggested [here](https://titan.as/exclude-wp-admin-preview-google-analytics/))
2. Used in the theme's functions.php file and not in .htaccess

I would like to use a similar tactic as the aforementioned article and add a query string var `analytics=false` when administrators are logged in and then I can add a filter to exclude urls that include the regex `analytics=false`.

What I have tried:

```
if(is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin()){
    if(current_user_can('administrator')){
        //not sure what to put here to add the query var
    }
}
```

Comment: You could put in the javascript that calls google analytics - how is your GA code being set up in your page? Are you using a plugin?

Comment: @willoller ah I didn't think about that. Yes, using theme.co's Google Analytics plugin. I should be able to find a way to hook in and do a conditional before the script is queued.

Comment: I think you can also exclude your own IP address - not a good solution for a nomad but okay if you're a homebody (officebody?)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just adding a bit more to the script that creates a pageview in analytics.

```
//check if we are logged in
if(!document.body.classList.contains('logged-in')){
  //we are not logged in, log a pageview
  ga('create', 'UA-123456-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

This doesn't work if you need to check if the user is admin or not but my site doesn't allow subscribers so it will work.

Thanks @willoller.

PS I cannot exclude my own IP as it changes everytime I reconnect to my VPN.

Comment: You could also check for the `admin-bar` class.

Comment: `logged-in` class is added when ever any type of user is logged in.

Comment: @Raunak I know...I said it won't work if you need to check user type in my answer

Comment: Sorry i did't notice that, I read your question there you have't mentioned that. btw if it is working for you then its good.